# Apps Script Creating a drop down based on an array

Tags: google-apps-script

first of all I want to apologize for my bad English I hope u will understand my problem.

I want to create, kind of an organizer for my upcoming school year. My plan is to get the subjects I have from the folder scructure in drive.

Example:

[Folder]
Schule
[Subfolder]
Mathe
[Subfolder]
Deutsch
[Subfolder]
Englisch

I already got it working so the subject Names are in an array.

Now I want to create a dropdown for example, that has all the different subjects as option (from the array). I didn't find anything like that yet is there a way to get this working?

I don't want to safe stuff in the spreadsheet if this even possible. But I think there is no way around to just make a sheet with Data. I don't want to safe the date cause it gets a bit messy from the things I can imagine cause I want to safe the different topics in the single subjects so I can automatically create a "Block" that says at this Date, Time, Subjets and these topics are going to be asked. I hope u understand what I want hehe. And for each topic I want to create a different subfolder in the subjects so I can. Just say trigger the function that will get all topics for the subject if I choose it in the dropdown before and give me these as Option.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var sub = []

function calendarentr() {
  var subject = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var kind = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var title = subject + " " + kind;
  var date = sheet.getRange('B5').getValue();
  
  CalendarApp.createAllDayEvent(title, date);

}


function getlist(){

  var main = DriveApp.getFolderById('1daOd6_z-pfPEPYjceJ5NQJ3aL5kCX7C4');
  var folders = main.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  sub.push(folder);
  Logger.log(sub);
}

}
```

[Englisch, Mathe, Deutsch]

That's the output for the array Sub.

that's what I got so far, but as I said I couldn't figure out how to get the values in the array as option in the dropdown. If its to complicated to solve it as I tried just say it and I will safe the values in another sheet and hide it.

Thanks for your help.

To get a Dropdown that has values from an array as option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I got it to work.

```
function getlist() {
  var main = DriveApp.getFolderById('1daOd6_z-pfPEPYjceJ5NQJ3aL5kCX7C4');
  var folders = main.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next()
    sub.push(folder);
    Logger.log(sub);

    var partrule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(sub).build();
    sheet.getRange('C3').setDataValidation(partrule);
  }
}
```

That's the final code thanks guys.